# Background Worker to update multiple items in a listview

Tags: c#, listview, backgroundworker

I am trying to update multiple values in a list box using this method: What this method does is copy the contents of the specified directory but it outputs the current file name to the background worker progress changed event.

```
private bool CopyDirectory(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath, bool Recursive, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Paths = new List<string>();
        List<string> Files = new List<string>();

        //for windows xp My documents
        if(!Directory.Exists(SourcePath))
        {
            SourcePath = SourcePath.Replace(@"C$\Users\", @"C$\Documents and Settings");

            int doccount = Regex.Matches(SourcePath, "Documents").Count;

            //if source contains 2 documents
            if(doccount > 1)
            {
                ReplaceLastOccurrence(SourcePath, "Documents", "My Documents");
            }
        }


        //set file permissions
        FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, SourcePath);
        f2.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;

        f2.Demand();

        foreach (string StringPath in DirectoryList(SourcePath, Recursive, null))
            Paths.Add(StringPath);
        foreach (string StringPath in FileList(SourcePath, Recursive, null))
            Files.Add(StringPath);
        try
        {

            foreach (string dirPath in Paths)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
            foreach (string newPath in Files)
            {



                string[] filename = newPath.Split('$');

                string currentfile = "C:" + filename[1];

                //report the file name to the background worker
                worker.ReportProgress(0, currentfile);


                System.IO.File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), Recursive);




            }
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }




    private static List<string> FileList(string RootDirectory,
        bool SearchAllDirectories, Predicate<string> Filter)
    {
        List<string> retList = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            List<string> DirList = new List<string> { RootDirectory };

            if (SearchAllDirectories)
                DirList.AddRange(DirectoryList(RootDirectory, SearchAllDirectories, Filter));

            foreach (string DirectoryStr in DirList)
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirectoryStr);
                try
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo FileStr in di.EnumerateFiles())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if ((Filter == null) || (Filter(FileStr.FullName)))
                                retList.Add(FileStr.FullName);
                        }

                        catch (Exception) { }
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return retList;
    }

    private static List<string> DirectoryList(string RootDirectory,
        bool SearchAllDirectories, Predicate<string> Filter)
    {
        List<string> retList = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(RootDirectory);

            foreach (DirectoryInfo DirectoryStr in di.EnumerateDirectories())
            {
                try
                {
                    if ((Filter == null) || (Filter(DirectoryStr.FullName)))
                    {
                        retList.Add(DirectoryStr.FullName);

                        if (SearchAllDirectories)
                            retList.AddRange(DirectoryList(DirectoryStr.FullName, SearchAllDirectories,
                                Filter));
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

                catch (Exception) { }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return retList;
    }
```

This works great for just one file name update, however, my program will do multiple copying of directors that i wish to update a list-view item to display it to the user.

```
private void bgwBackup_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeEx(c => this.lblBackupStatus.Text = e.UserState.ToString());
    }
```

My question is how would I update multiple listviewitems with the current filename of the specified path ? I can post my do work handler if needed. Thank you.

EDIT1 Here is my DO_WORK as requested:

```
  private void bgwBackup_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        //Textbox Array Values
        // 0 = computername
        // 1 = username
        // 2 = password
        string[] tbvalues = (string[])e.Argument;


        string computer = tbvalues[0];
        string user = tbvalues[1];
        string pass = tbvalues[2];






        try
        {
            //AD SEARCH

            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + user);
            string homepath = de.Properties["homedirectory"].Value.ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(homepath))
            {
                //do something when home drive is missing
                MessageBox.Show("NO H DRIVE");
            }

            else
            {

                //Declare strings 
                string os = GetOsName(computer);

                string desktop="";
                    string documents="";
                        string favorites="";

                        string outlooksig = "";
                        string outlookcache = "";


                        string hdriveroot = homepath + @"\PKBACKUP " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy--hh-mm-ss");

                        string hudp = hdriveroot + @"\Desktop";
                        string hudoc = hdriveroot + @"\Documents";
                        string hufav = hdriveroot + @"\Favorites";
                        string hprintdir = hdriveroot + @"\printers\";
                        string outlooksigdir = hdriveroot + @"\Outlook Files\Signatures";
                        string outlookcachedir = hdriveroot + @"\Outlook Files\Cache";






                if (os.Contains("XP"))
                {
                    desktop = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Documents and Settings\" + user + @"\Desktop";
                    documents = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Documents and Settings\" + user + @"\My Documents";
                    favorites = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Documents and Settings\" + user + @"\Favorites";

                    //outlook signatures
                    outlooksig = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Documents and Settings\" + user + @"\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures";

                    //outlook cache
                    outlookcache = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Documents and Settings\" + user + @"\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook";

                }


                else

                {
                    desktop = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Users\" + user + @"\Desktop";
                    documents = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Users\" + user + @"\Documents";
                    favorites = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Users\" + user + @"\Favorites";
                    outlooksig = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Users\" + user + @"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures";
                    outlookcache = @"\\" + computer + @"\C$\Users\" + user + @"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Outlook";


                }










                //Copy Files 
                using (new Impersonator(user, "Domain.org", pass))
                {

                   string outlookext = "nk2";

                    CopyDirectory(favorites, hufav, true, bgwBackup, e);
                   CopyDirectory(documents, hudoc, true, bgwBackup, e);
                    CopyDirectory(desktop, hudp, true, bgwBackup, e);
                    CopyDirectory(outlooksig, outlooksigdir, true, bgwBackup, e); 
                    copybyext(outlookcache, outlookcachedir, outlookext, user); //copy nk2 file method







                    //Printers 
                    List<string> printers = new List<string>();

                        foreach (string printername in lbBackupprinters.Items)
                        {
                            if (printername.Contains("No Printers Found"))
                            {
                                //Add listview entry that no printers were found
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                if (Directory.Exists(hprintdir) == false)
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(hprintdir);
                                }

                            string prntsvr;
                            string printer;

                            //strip out numbers in string
                            prntsvr = Regex.Replace(printername, "[^0-9]+", string.Empty);

                            //take the first number in the string
                            prntsvr = prntsvr[0].ToString();

                            //remote everything before last comma
                            printer = printername.Substring(printername.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);

                            //add vbs to printer name
                            printer = printer + ".vbs";

                            //get file path of printer vbs script
                            string[] printerpaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\dist-win-prnt-" + prntsvr + @"\printerscripts", printer);

                            //append string builder with print server path

                            if (!File.Exists(printerpaths[0]))
                            {
                                //do something if the printer does not exist, add error. 

                            }

                            else
                            {
                                printers.Add(printerpaths[0]);
                            }

                        }

                        string defaultprinter = lbBackupprinters.Items[0].ToString() + ".vbs";
                        defaultprinter = defaultprinter.Substring(defaultprinter.LastIndexOf(',') + 1);
                        //
                        //Download printer vbs script(s)
                        foreach (string printstring in printers)
                        {

                            string hprintfilename = printstring.Substring(printstring.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);




                            if (hprintfilename.Equals(defaultprinter))
                            {


                                File.Copy(printstring, hprintdir +  "(Defualt) "+ hprintfilename, true);

                            }

                            else
                            {



                                File.Copy(printstring, hprintdir + hprintfilename, true);
                            }

                        }

                    } // end else





                }
            }

        } //end try

        catch (Win32Exception logonfail)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("LOGON FAIL" + logonfail);

            //add label for failure
            return;

        }

        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException adfail)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(adfail.ToString());
        }

        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException accessex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(accessex.ToString());
        }






    }
```

EDIT2: Image of program [image]

EDIT3: Here is my progress changed and completed code

```
      //this only updates the status text and does not update the listview control. 
    private void bgwBackup_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeEx(c => this.lblBackupStatus.Text = e.UserState.ToString());
    }

    private void bgwBackup_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblBackupStatus.Text = "Backup job completed";
    }`
```

Comment: Plaese post doWork as well

Comment: Updated post with DO_WORK.

Comment: Can you clarify "This works great for just one file name update"?
What I understand is that you have several listviews (please tell for storing what exactly). What are the listviews' content before copying?
Do you want to copy concurrently using `Parallel` class?

Comment: I added a picture Peuczunski to help you get a better idea of what I want my program to do. Basically, the user would select a computer and a username and click add to queue. Once they have all the computers they want, they would press Start Backup. This would display the current file the system is copying in the "Current File" list view column, for multiple machines.

Comment: I also updated my report progress and completed. Thanks for your help so far, also yes, I would like to Parallel the operation.

Comment: OK, now I get the problem 100%. In a while I will present a little bit different approach that should solve your problem

Comment: Why is there so much whitespace in the code?! Please format the code properly. Also, you should read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Try to keep it short and concise.

Answer (score 5):

First, add another class

```
class BackupTask
{
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string CurrentFile { get; set; }
    public int OverallProgress { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
private List<BackupTask> task_definitions = new List<BackupTask>();  //this is needed to parallel foreach 
private List<BackupTask> tasks = new List<BackupTask>();  //this is what you will use to report progress of your copying
```

and suppose your backgroundworker is named 'bw`

`private BackgroundWorker bw;`

Add this to your XAML file (before main Grid)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BackupTask">            
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineName}" Margin="2,4,2,4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}" Margin="2,4,2,4" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Password}" Margin="2,4,2,4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentFile}" Margin="2,4,2,4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OverallProgress}" Margin="2,4,2,4"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

in your listview set `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BackupTask}`

So in the window constructor

```
bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
```

Your buttons

```
private void btn_AddToQueue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackupTask bt = new BackupTask();
    bt.MachineName = //load these
    bt.Username = // from your 
    bt.Password = //textboxes
    bt.CurrentFile = "";
    bt.OverallProgress = 0;
    AddOrModifyTask(bt);    
    listView1.ItemsSource = tasks;
}


private void btn_StartBackup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!bw.IsBusy)
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Of cource you will also need

```
void AddOrModifyTask(BackupTask t)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (BackupTask bt in tasks)
    {
        if (bt.MachineName == t.MachineName)
        {
            found = true;
            bt.CurrentFile = t.CurrentFile;
            bt.OverallProgress = t.OverallProgress;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        tasks.Add(t);
}
```

Your progressbar events

```
void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lock (tasks)
    {
        AddOrModifyTask((BackupTask)e.UserState);
    }
    listView1.ItemsSource = tasks;
    listView1.Items.Refresh();
}


void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    task_definitions = tasks;
    Parallel.ForEach(task_definitions, task =>
        {
            string computer = task.MachineName;
            string user = task.Username;
            string pass = task.Password;
            //your old Do_Work code
        });
}
```

Instead of passing background worker as parameter pass associated BackupTask object and always use bw

Quick working example is [here](http://www.theoutsourcing.pl/parallelprogress.zip)

Comment: Thanks for all the code, i have a few questions. I'm using Windows Forms Application and for `lvBackupqueue.Items.Refresh();` im getting a missing  a using directive or assemly reference. Do i need to add a specific reference to my project to use that ? Also i don't seem to have an XAML file. Thanks.

Comment: There is no DataBinding in Winforms. If you really must use Winforms you have to make databinding manually. If not migrate this project to WPF

Comment: Did I miss something in my answer? Because it hasn't been accepted yet you didn't report further problems.

Comment: Sorry I was out on vacation for a week. I'll take a look at migrating to WPF but it might be too steep of a learning curve for me.